# Solving Non Linear Equations for multiple values in python

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

**problem**:Unable to solve a unknown for multiple known values in a non-linear equation

```
def iv(p):

    Io=2.02*10**-6
    n=1.6
    Isc_ref=4.37
    Il=Isc_ref
    voc_ref=42.93
    Ns=72
    a=(Ns*n*k*Tref)/q
    Rsh=(voc_ref)/(Il-(Io*(np.exp(voc_ref/a)-1)))
    RS=0.01  
    k=1.38*10**-23
    q=1.602*10**-19
    Tref=25+273


    I=p
    v=33.5

    diode=Il-(Io*(np.exp((v+(I*RS))/a)-1))-((v+(I*RS))/Rsh)-I

    return diode

I=opt.fsolve(iv,3)
```

(I) is the unknown and (v) is the known value and the rest are constants.I could solve this for one value of v.
**Solution Needed:** (1)How would I solve (I) for multiple values of v?
                     (2)Like wise then how do i solve for (I) if the constants   (Rs,Io,Il,Rsh,a) are in different dataframes of 8760 rows and 91 columns?

Comment: In your code ``k,Tref,q`` are not defined. To use ``scipy.opt`` you need formulate your problem as: Minimize ``f(q)``where ``q`` is the vector with your parameters you want to optimize. You'll find many examples at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: sorry for that..i didnt notice it..i just added the values of (k,q,Tref)...thanks